# Linking HTML form action to node js function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to execute a function in node.js when a users enters information on a form in html. I keep getting 404 not found and am not sure where to go. I'm sure there are other questions similar to this but have searched around and can't find anything.

HTML Code:

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href = "style.css" />

<form action="/zipCheck" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input placeholder="Enter your zip code to start" class = "zipInput">
</form>

</html>
```

Node.js code:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

console.log("hello");

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(logger('short'));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.post('/zipCheck', function(req, res){
    console.log("GOOD");
});

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Where and when are you _"getting 404 not found"_? What actions lead to that response? What do you expect `next(createError(404))` to do? You aren't executing that conditionally at all

Comment: @Phil I commented out the next(createError(404)) use function and still got a 404 error

Comment: Try `app.post('/zipCheck', ...`

Comment: @Phil still no. I'm using phpStorm and it does say `Unresolved function or method post()`. Is that an issue?

Comment: Could you please update the code in your question to match what you currently have?

Comment: @Phil haven’t changed anything. Tried putting a backslash before zipCode but that didn’t fix it so I deleted it. The code above is representative of the code I have

Comment: But you still have your `next(createError(404))` catch-all without any condition. You said you commented that out 

Comment: @Phil yes but that didn’t work either so I added it back in

Comment: use this app.post('/zipCheck', .....) middleware before app.use('/', indexRouter);

Comment: @Dharani This still didn't fix it. Code updated

Comment: @Dharani do I have all the correct middleware or are there any I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

> The order of middleware loading is important: middleware functions that are loaded first are also executed first.

You added the `/zipCheck` route after the error handler, your requests will never reach this handler and
your app will not print `GOOD`.

You need to reorder your routes handler, also add a slash before `zipCheck`

```
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.post('/zipCheck', function(req, res){
    console.log("GOOD");
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    
})
```

Comment: Are you still getting 404 or no response at all ? Do you see "GOOD"  in the `console` ? Btw, you should send the response in the route handler  `app.post('/zipCheck', function(req, res){ console.log("GOOD"); res.send({ok: 'ok'}); })`

Comment: Yes I'm still getting the 404 response. I also get the 404 error when I navigate to `localhost/app.js/zipCheck`, but when I navigate to `localhost/app.js` it just displays the text of the `app.js` file

Comment: You can't test  `/zipCheck` route by navigating to `localhost:3000/zipCheck`, you should submit the html form or use an API client like postman. Here is a Repl.it of your updated code, you can try it here https://repl.it/repls/VapidDryFilesize

Comment: How do I navigate to a different page after submission? And why does the response show on the `repl.it` but not in my browser?

Comment: Copy the URL in the browser section in this case https://VapidDryFilesize--five-nine.repl.co, then you can navigate to https://VapidDryFilesize--five-nine.repl.co/users for example, you can redirect after submission `res.redirect('/users')`

Comment: And how come I see `{"ok":"ok Test"}` in the repl, but when I run mine I still get the 404 error? Shouldn't mine also show `{"ok":"ok Test"}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217488/discussion-between-marshall-scudder-and-mousto090).