# HTML Form post request results in 502 bad gateway when calling php file

Tags: php, html, rest

I have two files:

Homepage.html:

```
<html lang="en">

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>

<link rel = "stylesheet"
      type = "text/css"
      href = "style.css" />

<form action="zipTest.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input placeholder="Enter your zip code to start" class = "zipInput">
</form>

</html>
```

and
zipTest.php:

```
<?php

print("Post successful");

?>
```

I should see "Post successful" in the console with this code right? But I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway error after submitting the form. What is wrong?

Comment: You don;t have `submit` button so you are not even submitting the form right now.

Comment: And on that you don't even have a body tag

Comment: @Lucifere I'm pressing enter inside the input field, isn't that equivalent to pressing a button? I don't want a button. I want the user to be able to press enter and submit the form that way.

Comment: @Lucifer body tag didn't help either

Comment: Yes it is possible but you will need js for it.

Comment: @Lucifer check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747974/linking-html-form-action-to-node-js-function

Answer (score 0):

You don't need additional HTML tags or javascript for this to work.
If you dont do anything weird in your app.js this should work by pressing enter in the input.
The text won't bevisible in the console but rather in the browser page.

Check this:

- Are both Homepage.html and zipTest.php in the same directory? Lets say Homepage.html is in the webroot then the url for this page is: http://localhost/Homepage.html. If you press enter in the input it should change url to: http://localhost/zipTest.php. This doesn't have to be via POST. Just go to this url in the browser and it should output the text you defined. If it doesn't the url is wrong, for example both files are in different directories.
- does your server even support php files? Go to location of the php file directly in your browser and find out. Do other php files work?

Comment: I get the 502 bad gateway error when I try and open the php page in a web browser. Does this mean my web browser doesn't support php files?

Comment: @MarshallScudder not your web browser. Your server. JS is executed in the browser, PHP is executed on the server. What server do you use? Apache/Nginx/PHP development server? Locally? Shared hosting? And it doesnt mean it doesnt support php, it means there is some configuration issue. Check your server logs. Also you wrote you expect to see this text in the console - maybe you just wanted to use JS